# How to Query application metrics through Prometheus nagios_plugin

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

```
mn1~/nagios_plugins# PROMETHEUS_SERVER='http://10.93.123.4:9090'

mn1~/nagios_plugins# QUERY_VECTOR_UP='up{instance="10.85.10.131:9116"}'                                                 mn1~/nagios_plugins# bash check_prometheus_metric.sh -H $PROMETHEUS_SERVER -q $QUERY_VECTOR_UP -w 1 -c 1 -n $QUERY_VECTOR_UP -m lt -t vector -i
CRITICAL - up{instance="10.85.10.131:9116"} is 0: { __name__: up, instance: 10.85.10.131:9116, job: prometheus }

mn1~/nagios_plugins# curl -v http://10.85.10.131:9116/snmp?target="127.0.0.1" | more
*   Trying 10.85.10.131...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 10.85.10.131 (10.85.10.131) port 9116 (#0)
> GET /snmp?target=127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.85.10.131:9116
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 05 May 2023 09:12:10 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{ [6257 bytes data]
1# HELP sc_crld
# TYPE sc_crld counter
sc_crld 1
# HELP sc_device_pki_certificates
# TYPE sc_device_pki_certificates counter
sc_device_pki_certificates 0
# HELP sc_log_exporter
# TYPE sc_log_exporter counter
sc_log_exporter 0
# HELP sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn
# TYPE sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn counter
sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn 2
# HELP sc_pcd_g2version
# TYPE sc_pcd_g2version counter
sc_pcd_g2version 0

mn1~/nagios_plugins# QUERY_VECTOR_UP='sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn{instance="10.85.10.131:9116"}'
mn1~/nagios_plugins# bash check_prometheus_metric.sh -H $PROMETHEUS_SERVER -q $QUERY_VECTOR_UP -w 1 -c 1 -n $QUERY_VECTOR_UP -m lt -t vector -i
UNKNOWN - unable to parse prometheus response: null
sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn{instance="10.85.10.131:9116"} is null
mn1~/nagios_plugins#
```

How to query sc_pcd_encryption_server_cdn metric with check_prometheus_metric nagios plugin? metrics are available through snmp exporter running on 9116. We are able to pull all the metrics start with "sc_" I am looking to query and pull all the metrics available on port 9116 thru nagios plugin check_prometheus_metric.sh

Comment: I'm not familiar with snmp_exporter, but I doubt that it will put own address into instance field. Try query `{__name__=~"sc_.*"}` and look what instance labels are returned.